# To show Fourier transform of a integrable function vanishes identically.

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

Let $f\in L^{1}(\mathbb{R})$ that satisfies
$$\int_0^\infty e^{itz}\widehat{f}(t)dt=0,\forall z\in \mathbb{H},$$
where $\mathbb{H}$ is the open upper half plane.

Does the above condition implies that $\widehat{f}$ vanishes identically on $[0,\infty)$?